# TypeORM not converting `Date` to utc

Tags: date, serialization, typeorm

Lets start by providing the database definition of the entity in question:

```js
    @Column({ name: "last_seen", type: "timestamp", nullable: true })
    @Index()
    public lastSeen: Date | null = null;

    @CreateDateColumn({ name: "created", type: "timestamp", nullable: false })
    public created!: Date;
```

The database is UTC but the server (in development) is in the "Asia/Tehran" time zone. As far as I know, TypeORM should store dates in UTC and convert them back to local time on retrieval.

However, and I think this is happening recently since I don't remember having a similar issue on this project which is ongoing for 6 months now, but the Dates are now stored raw. For example, if I save `10:00+4:30` in javascript for the `lastSeen` property it will be saved invalidly as `10:00`.

On the other hand, when reading dates that are created by the database in "UTC" automatically, for example as is the case for the `created` property, the value is read in the local timezone instead of getting converted from "UTC". In these cases, the data is stored correctly in the Database in "UTC".

Is there an option that I am missing here in regard to date time conversion with TypeORM?

Comment: I think you have to use ```timestamptz``` (timestamp with timezone) instead of the basic ```timestamp```. See [this](https://medium.com/building-the-system/how-to-store-dates-and-times-in-postgresql-269bda8d6403) article for more information.
Moreover, as far as I know, ```timestamptz``` *is always* the best/suggested approach.

Comment: It makes no sense tho, TimestamptZ stores time zone data and it can make the DB more complicated instead of helping with it.

Comment: @CarloCorradini ok, it makes sense, thanks, will try, the naming here with timestamp and timestamptz is bad, to say the least.

Comment: Maybe you can add the answer so that this question shows up higher in searches. Indeed the `timestamp with time zone` approach helped me after a few hours of research. I was trying to prevent using timezone in the database as well, but simply throwing away the offset instead of taking it into account while there are no advantages to doing so makes no sense; at least not yet until someone points to another article that refutes the one @CarloCorradini sent.

Comment: @Pedram Done! Hope it helps! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`timestamptz`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-datetime.html) (timestamp with timezone) instead of the basic `timestamp`.

See [this article](https://medium.com/building-the-system/how-to-store-dates-and-times-in-postgresql-269bda8d6403) for more information.